How do I use XSalsa20 and Poly1305 primitives in Bouncycastle for AEAD
I want to use BouncyCastle to immitate the default AEAD scheme of libsodium (X25519 ECDH followed by XSalsa20 symmetric cipher with Poly1305 KDF).
I was able to do the DH with X25519 KeyAgreement to generate a javax.crypto.SecretKey.
But for the next step I'm left clueless. BouncyCastle offers a ChaCha20Poly1305 class implementing AEADCipher, which seems to be doing both steps at once (generating MAC and encrypting). However, I did not find any such equivalent for "XSalsa20Poly1305".
There is a Poly1305KeyGenerator available in BC, but I don't see any way to pass a nonce to it, since it accepts only a simple KeyGenerationParameters objects on init.
Why is the combination of ChaCha20 and Poly1305 so special (compared to [X]Salsa20+Poly1305) that it has a dedicated implementation? How can I do the same thing for XSalsa20 with BouncyCastle primitives?

Libsodium applies XSalsa20-Poly1305 for authenticated encryption, which is implemented in the function crypto_secretbox_easy(). The underlying algorithm of XSalsa20-Poly1305 can be read from the reference implementation:

With HSalsa20 and the key k and the nonce n as input parameters, a key subkey is derived.
With Salsa20, using the key subkey and the last 8 bytes of n as nonce (called subnonce in the following), the concatenation of an empty 32 bytes array and the plaintext m of length mlen is encrypted.
The first 32 bytes are used as the Poly1305 key, the rest is the actual ciphertext c.
With Poly1305, the Poly1305 MAC mac is derived for c applying the Poly1305 key.

For further details on the algorithms, in particular HSalsa20, see e.g. Extending the Salsa20 nonce, and on authentication, see e.g. Poly1305.
BouncyCastle implements XSalsa20Engine as derivation of Salsa20Engine. XSalsa20Engine overwrites setKey(), which implements HSalsa20 and internally determines subkey and subnonce. When the XSalsa20Engine instance is initialized, Salsa20Engine#init() is executed and thus setKey().
This allows XSalsa20-Poly1305 to be implemented with Bouncycastle as follows:

Initialization of the XSalsa20Engine using key and nonce. This internally calculates subkey and subnonce.
Encryption of the empty 32 byte array with Salsa20 using subkey and subnonce to derive the Poly1305 key.
Encryption of the plaintext with Salsa20 using subkey and subnonce to the ciphertext.
For the sake of simplicity, both are done separately (alternatively, the concatenation of the empty 32 bytes array and the plaintext could be encrypted as in the reference implementation).
Calculation of the Poly1305 MAC for the ciphertext using the Poly1305 key.

In addition, a random nonce is generated (this is done in the reference implementation before the crypto_secretbox_easy() call), and nonce, Poly1305 MAC and ciphertext are concatenated in this order.
Regarding the Poly1305 key, please note the following:

Poly1305 is used in the context of XSalsa20Poly1305 as a one-time authenticator whose key is 32 bytes in size, see e.g. here.
For Poly1305 keys, a number of bits are cleared (clamping) by definition. macKey in the above procedure is not (yet) clamped, this only happens implicitly during the initialization of Poly1305 (in init() via setKey()).
So if you want to check macKey with checkKey(), clamp() must be executed first (the subsequent implicit clamping during Poly1305 initialization then has no effect).
Poly1305KeyGenerator or generateKey() must not be used to generate the Poly1305 key in the context of XSalsa20-Poly1305. generateKey() is intended for the generation of random Poly1305 keys, while the Poly1305 key generated in the context of XSalsa20-Poly1305 is generated deterministically (in the way described above).

Example implementation for encryption with XSalsa20-Poly1305:
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HexFormat;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.XSalsa20Engine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.macs.Poly1305;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays;
...
static final int NONCEBYTES = 24;
static final int KEYBYTES = 32;
...
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] plaintext) {
    
    // generate random nonce
    byte[] nonce = new byte[NONCEBYTES];
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secureRandom.nextBytes(nonce);

    XSalsa20Engine xSalsa20Engine = new XSalsa20Engine();
    xSalsa20Engine.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), nonce));
    
    // generate mac key
    byte[] macKey = new byte[KEYBYTES];
    xSalsa20Engine.processBytes(macKey, 0, macKey.length, macKey, 0);

    // encrypt plaintext
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[plaintext.length];
    xSalsa20Engine.processBytes(plaintext, 0, plaintext.length, ciphertext, 0);
    
    // generate mac
    Poly1305 poly1305 = new Poly1305();
    poly1305.init(new KeyParameter(macKey));
    byte[] mac = new byte[poly1305.getMacSize()];
    poly1305.update(ciphertext, 0, plaintext.length); // ciphertext size = plaintext size
    poly1305.doFinal(mac, 0);

    // concatenate, e.g. nonce|mac|ciphertext
    return Arrays.concatenate(nonce, mac, ciphertext);
}

Example for decryption:
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] nonceMacCiphertext) {
    
    // separate nonce, mac and ciphertext
    Poly1305 poly1305 = new Poly1305();
    byte[] nonce = Arrays.copyOfRange(nonceMacCiphertext, 0, NONCEBYTES);
    byte[] mac  = Arrays.copyOfRange(nonceMacCiphertext, NONCEBYTES, NONCEBYTES + poly1305.getMacSize());
    byte[] ciphertext  = Arrays.copyOfRange(nonceMacCiphertext, NONCEBYTES + poly1305.getMacSize(), nonceMacCiphertext.length);
    
    XSalsa20Engine xSalsa20Engine = new XSalsa20Engine();
    xSalsa20Engine.init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), nonce));
    
    // generate mac key
    byte[] macKey = new byte[KEYBYTES];
    xSalsa20Engine.processBytes(macKey, 0, macKey.length, macKey, 0);

    // calculate Mac
    byte[] macCalculated = new byte[poly1305.getMacSize()];
    poly1305.init(new KeyParameter(macKey));
    poly1305.update(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length);
    poly1305.doFinal(macCalculated, 0);

    // decrypt on successful authentication
    byte[] decrypted = null;
    if (MessageDigest.isEqual(macCalculated, mac)) {
        decrypted = new byte[ciphertext.length];
        xSalsa20Engine.processBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length, decrypted, 0);
    }
    return decrypted;
}


Test:
The most convenient way to check compatibility with XSalsa20-Poly1305 is to compare a ciphertext generated with a Libsodium library, e.g. Lazysodium, and identical input parameters:
import com.goterl.lazysodium.LazySodiumJava;
import com.goterl.lazysodium.SodiumJava;
import com.goterl.lazysodium.utils.Key;
...
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Check XSalsa20-Poly1305 implementation
    byte[] key = HexFormat.of().parseHex("a7e845b0854294da9aa743b807cb67b19647c1195ea8120369f3d12c70468f29");
    byte[] plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);        

    byte[] nonceMacCiphertext = encrypt(key, plaintext);
    System.out.println("CT, BouncyCastle: " + HexFormat.of().formatHex(nonceMacCiphertext)); 

    byte[] decrypted = decrypt(key, nonceMacCiphertext);
    System.out.println("Decrypted data:   " + new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

    // Compare nonce|mac|ciphertext with Lazysodium
    byte[] nonce = Arrays.copyOfRange(nonceMacCiphertext, 0, NONCEBYTES);
    SodiumJava sodium = new SodiumJava();
    LazySodiumJava lazySodium = new LazySodiumJava(sodium, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String macCiphertext = lazySodium.cryptoSecretBoxEasy("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", nonce , Key.fromBytes(key));
    System.out.println("CT, Lazysodium:   " + HexFormat.of().formatHex(nonce) + macCiphertext.toLowerCase()); 
}

Both ciphertexts match for identical input data.

I don't get this code... Why are you feeding an empty array to salsa engine to produce the mac key? Isn't this what's Poly1305KeyGenerator for? Is this some kind of performance optimization trick?

then why does checking the "deterministically derived" key fail BouncyCastle's Poly1305KeyGenerator#checkKey() verification? It seems like the key is not a valid Poly1305 key - it throws IAE: Invalid format for r portion of Poly1305 key.
I also searched the linked whitepapers of [X]Salsa20, and there is not mention of any Poly1305 keys, so why should it behave differently when used with other ciphers?

Furthermore, I found various references that state " Poly1305 takes as input a 16-byte key (with some specific bits set to zero) and a message of arbitrary length and outputs a 16-byte digest of the message. The output of Poly1305 is the truncation (to 16 bytes) of a polynomial evaluated in F2130−5 at the key r (which first has certain bits ‘clamped’ to zero); " https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/613.pdf That does not fit with just plainly setting a zero input every time.

@Leprechaun - I have revised my post (see the part before the example implementation) and answered (among others) your questions from the comments (especially the questions about the origin of the empty 32 byte array, about clamping and about the Poly1305 key size). This should make the BouncyCastle implementation more transparent.

Oof, this took me a long while to digest, I had to read Bernstein's papers, ChaCha RFCs, rubberduck libsodium code and crossreference BC with your step by step overview.
I think(?) you are correct in every claim you make, so I'm accepting the answer, thanks.
It would be much simpler if someone would write a big disclaimer somewhere saying that XSalsa20-Poly1305 from libsodium is not the same thing as XSalsa20 + Poly1305. Really, the recipe on what to do must be deciphered from Bernstein's paper Cryptography in NaCl. IMHO it should even get it's own distinct name as an AEAD scheme.
